# Motivation for Using Static Factory Methods

Tags: java

The motivation for using Static Factory methods staes as:

> The most obvious motivation for Replace Constructor with Factory
>   Method comes with replacing a type code with subclassing.
>
> You have an object that often is created with a type code but now
>   needs subclasses. The exact subclass is based on the type code.
>
> However, constructors can only return an instance of the object that
>   is asked for. So you need to replace the constructor with a factory
>   method.

Can anyone please explain this with code? And what does this **type code** mean?

Comment: Please add a link to the source where you read this.

Comment: @RohitJain I just looked it up to quote his question, it's from [here](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-constructor-with-factory-method)

Comment: You have an example in your book. What else do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine we have a `Person` class with a field called `type` to indicate if that person is a teacher or a student. This will be the type code.

Now imagine we replace this type field with an object hierarchy: `Person` class with 2 subclasses `Teacher` and `Student`.

If I use the constructors then I can only create a specific type of person i.e. `new Teacher()` or `new Student()`

but if I want a method that creates a different kind of person based on some logic then I can do:

```
public static Person newPerson() {
   // can return either a Teacher or a Student
}
```

Comment: You should probably provide some arguments to `newPerson` to make it realistic.

Answer (score 2):

A second advantage that a factory method has over a bare constructor is that it can return an existing object.  The `Integer.valueOf(int)` method makes good use of this.  By contrast, `new` always creates a new object.

Finally, if we broaden the discussion slightly, a non-static factory method (e.g. in the form of a factory *object*) allow you use polymorphism to implement different object creation strategies.

---

> And what does this type code mean?

You need to read this in the context of the page that you got this from.  What the page is talking about is a single class that represents different "types" of thing.  (In the example given, it is different types of employee represented by one `Employee` class.)  The "type code" is simply the attribute of the class that discriminates the different types.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor can only return one implementation, however a static factory method can return any number of implementations, often a sub-class of the class referred to. Static factory methods also have the advantage of being named so you can have different behaviour for the same arguments.

e.g. These two methods return a sub-class of EnumSet (based on the number of elements in the enum) with different values based on the name (even though the arguements are the same)

```
EnumSet<MemoryType> memoryTypes = EnumSet.noneOf(MemoryType.class);
EnumSet<MemoryType> memoryTypes2 = EnumSet.allOf(MemoryType.class);
```

From the source

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> noneOf(Class<E> elementType) {
    Enum[] universe = getUniverse(elementType);
    if (universe == null)
        throw new ClassCastException(elementType + " not an enum");

    if (universe.length <= 64)
        return new RegularEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
    else
        return new JumboEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
}
```

You can see it has one implementation for smaller enum sets and another for larger ones.

Comment: What does this sentence mean : Factory Method comes with replacing a type code with subclassing. What do they mean by replacing a type code with subclassing.

Comment: In the example above, the factory method has a return type of `EnumSet` which is abstract, and can chose to return one of the sub-classes `RegularEnumSet` or `JumboEnumSet`